# Need to pull backward records while querying records between date range

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

Below is the sample table

```
id  date         rating
-----------------------
1   15-11-2015    A
1   18-11-2015    A
1   05-12-2015    B
2   05-11-2015    A
2   21-11-2015    A
2   05-12-2015    A
3   25-11-2015    B
3   05-12-2015    B
     .....
```

Now my service is querying about rating for id 1, 2, 3 (could be more in number also) between date 01-DEC-2015 to 10-DEC-2015. As If I make select query to pull records within this range there is only one record that is of 05-DEC-2015.

So on JAVA side I can use that to fill same data until 10-DEC as that is applicable. but for backward filling, I need to pull previous record (pull just one record prior to 01-DEC-2015 there could be n records before this date) for each ID which is necessarily not on same date for all Ids. Can some please help me with query for this or if query is not at all possible, then with SP.

Required output is as below; for ratings between 01-12-2015 to 10-12-2015 of id 1,2

```
    1   18-11-2015    A
    1   05-12-2015    B
    2   21-11-2015    A
    2   05-12-2015    A
```

as there is not rating on start date (01-12-2015) i need to pull previous rating for each ID.

Initially try was as below; this would have worked if rating dates been same for all ids, but unfortunately that is not the case.

```
Select * 
from ratings rr 
where rr.id in (1, 2) 
  and rr.date between (Select max(rrr.date) 
                       from ratings rrr 
                       where rrr.date <= to_date('01-12-2015','dd-MM-yyyy')) 
                  and to_date('10-12-2015','dd-MM-yyyy')
```

Comment: Can you please post your needed result?

Comment: I have updated my question with required output.

Answer (score 1):

If I have your requirements correct - you want to get the results between a given range for each `id` value and, if there are not at least two rows per `id` then get rows from before this range until there are two rows per id.

You can do this by filtering on the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function `OR` rows being within the `date` range.:

```
SELECT id,
       "date",
       rating
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         "date",
         rating,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "date" DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   ratings
  WHERE  "date" <= DATE '2015-12-10'
  AND    id     IN ( 1, 2 )
)
WHERE "date" >= DATE '2015-12-01' 
OR    rn <= 2;
```

If the requirement is to get all the rows from within the range and also exactly one rows with the latest date preceding the range then you can do it using `UNION`:

```
SELECT id,
       "date",
       rating
FROM   ratings
WHERE  "date" BETWEEN DATE '2015-12-01' AND DATE '2015-12-10'
AND    id IN ( 1, 2 )
UNION ALL
SELECT id,
       "date",
       rating
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         "date",
         rating,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "date" ) AS rn
  FROM   ratings
  WHERE  "date" < DATE '2015-12-01'
  AND    id IN ( 1, 2 )
)
WHERE   rn = 1;
```

Comment: this is really helpful.My scenario was second one, But in actual my query is very much complex with two unions as data is coming from two different sources. Can you please help me with some analytic function that can define incremental row-number if this is outside the range. so that i can pick one only

Comment: Sounds like you could use a sub-query factoring clause: `WITH ratings ( id, "date", rating ) AS ( <YOUR_COMPLICATED_QUERY> ) <MY_QUERY_WITH_THE_UNION>`